# Sorting killing my postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "issues" 
INNER JOIN "assets" ON "issues"."asset_id" = "assets"."id" 
WHERE "assets"."project_id" = 1 
AND "issues"."active" = 't' 
AND "issues"."phase" IN ('open');
```

which runs in 1057.612ms with the following query plan:

```
> Aggregate  (cost=104434.64..104434.65 rows=1 width=0) (actual
> time=1057.289..1057.289 rows=1 loops=1)    ->  Merge Join 
> (cost=4449.93..103041.81 rows=557132 width=0) (actual
> time=1011.340..1052.960 rows=23355 loops=1)
>          Merge Cond: (assets.id = issues.asset_id)
>          ->  Sort  (cost=4421.47..4482.58 rows=24444 width=4) (actual time=30.097..35.907 rows=24241 loops=1)
>                Sort Key: assets.id
>                Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 336kB
>                ->  Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..2639.85 rows=24444 width=4) (actual time=0.009..15.827 rows=24241 loops=1)
>                      Filter: (project_id = 581)
>                      Rows Removed by Filter: 54307
>          ->  Index Only Scan using index_issues_on_asset_id_and_active_and_phase_and_severity on issues 
> (cost=0.43..88451.15 rows=1790279 width=4) (actual time=0.019..659.942
> rows=1878712 loops=1)
>                Index Cond: ((active = true) AND (phase = 'open'::text))
>                Filter: active
>                Heap Fetches: 0  Total runtime: 1057.612 ms (14 rows)
```

If I turn sorting with `set enable_sort=off;` I get a significant performance boost:

```
> `Aggregate  (cost=112186.16..112186.17 rows=1 width=0) (actual
> time=85.151..85.151 rows=1 loops=1)    ->  Nested Loop 
> (cost=0.43..110793.33 rows=557132 width=0) (actual time=0.027..80.705
> rows=23355 loops=1)
>          ->  Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..2639.85 rows=24444 width=4) (actual time=0.010..16.213 rows=24241 loops=1)
>                Filter: (project_id = 581)
>                Rows Removed by Filter: 54307
>          ->  Index Only Scan using index_issues_on_asset_id_and_active_and_phase_and_severity on issues 
> (cost=0.43..3.78 rows=64 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1
> loops=24241)
>                Index Cond: ((asset_id = assets.id) AND (active = true) AND (phase = 'open'::text))
>                Filter: active
>                Heap Fetches: 0  Total runtime: 85.184 ms (10 rows) `
```

Obviously I want the better performance. How can I get it without turning off sorting? What can I do better? I've analyzed and vacuumed the tables and it speeds things up by milliseconds (but not hundreds of milliseconds)

```
select version();
```

> ```
> PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, 
> compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
> ```

Comment: The first plan was generated with a cold run or after other executions of the same query?

Comment: They were both after many executions of the same query.

Comment: The slow part of your query was not the sort (even though the sort occurred on disk), right? It looks like the slow part was the index-only scan  on `issues` which in the first plan didn't apply the predicate on `asset_id` but in the second plan did.

Comment: *nodding* I guess that the plan inferred that it didn't need to because it had just sorted?? Or it was going to sort for the merge?

Comment: I don't know enough about the way that postgresql chooses between various options for query plans. Maybe something to do with the statistics available leading it to give poor estimates about the number of rows that would match various predicates.

Comment: Try rewriting the query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "issues", "assets" WHERE "issues"."asset_id" = "assets"."id" AND "assets"."project_id" = 1 AND "issues"."active" = 't' AND "issues"."phase" IN ('open');`

Comment: That produces an identical plan.

Comment: How is `index_issues_on_asset_id_and_active_and_phase_and_severity` defined? Post the `CREATE INDEX` definition. Have you tried `VACUUM ANALYZE issues;`?

Comment: ` CREATE INDEX index_issues_on_asset_id_and_active_and_phase_and_severity ON issues USING btree (asset_id, active, phase, severity)`

And, I've vacuumed and analyzed issues (and all tables) with little obvious success.

Comment: Try creating an index for each column. It seems that the planner doesn't use the index in the proper way.

Comment: Your query plans do not match your query text.  The plans have a condition of `project_id = 581` but your query has something different.